# I have Shape Area and Shape Length of a polygon shapefile. How can I convert these to geometries in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I downloaded a csv file for a GIS dataset of wildfires. The shapefile contains polygons, and while the csv does not contain the lat/long coordinates, it does contain the Shape_Area and Shape_Length that is typical with polygon feature classes. I want to convert these to geometries in PostgreSQL. Is there a way to do this? I'm aware of the ST_Area function but the documentation on postgis.net doesn't seem like what I'm looking for. I'm a beginner with postgis.

Example:

GIS Acres | Shape_Area | Shape_Length
100   |  733134.7  |   4179.75